# How to wait for batch file to end when called from python?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I have a batch file which is zipping a folder as follows(zip.bat):

```
for /d %%X in (D:/sample/target/bin) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -mx "%%X.zip" "%%X\*"
```

The batch file will zip folder bin and works correctly. Now am calling this batch from a python script as follows:

```
import subprocess as sp
import sys
start_zip_batch = sp.Popen(['D:/zip.bat'],stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE, shell = True)
start_zip_batch.wait()
```

So, now when the script is made to execute it creates the bin.zip folder but keep showing 0 bytes inside it and after a while it stops responding and i need to manually close it. The bin folder is around 403 mb. So, please suggest how shall i call zip.bat from python such that it creates te zip folder and then gets closed neatly.

Comment: Use `start_zip_batch.communicate()` to prevent the `stdout` and `stderr` pipes from filling up and blocking. But why are you setting the input and output to pipes? If you don't require standard input and output, you can set the standard streams to `subprocess.DEVNULL` in Python 3, or to `fnull = open(os.devnull, 'r+')` in Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

There are several subprocess methods that wait for completion.

`check_call` is useful if you want to do cleanup or reporting based on the command return code.

> subprocess.check_call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None,
>   shell=False)
>
> Run command with arguments. Wait for command to complete. If the return code was zero then return, otherwise raise CalledProcessError.
>   The CalledProcessError object will have the return code in the
>   returncode attribute.

[The Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

Answer (score 0):

```c
print('filename')
```

would work if you do not have any output in the `.bat` file

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most modern way is to use [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) which executes the process and waits for it to complete:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.run(['D:/zip.bat'])
```

This will execute the process and return a [`CompletedProcess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess) object for which you can inspect the `returncode` attribute to determine that status.

The process's stdout and stderr destinations are unchanged, e.g. output will still appear on the terminal if the command is run from a terminal.

You can capture the output of both stdout and stderr if you want:

```
p = subprocess.run(['D:/zip.bat'], capture_output=True)
print(p.stdout.decode())
print(p.stderr.decode())
```